# How to get the count of Left and right referral ids with laravel eloquent query

Tags: php, laravel

Hello experts I am totally new with php and laravel. Can you suggest me with laravel 5.1 eloquent query how to get the total count of left referrals and right also.  Thanks in advance

[image]

```
public function downline_count($uids, $count)
{
  $donwlines = Downline::whereIn('user_id', [$uids])->get();

  $uids = '';
  foreach($donwlines as $downline)
  {
    if( $downline->left_member_id > 0)
    {
      $uids .= $downline->left_member_id.',';  
    $count = $count +1;
    }

    if( $downline->right_member_id > 0)
    {
      $uids .=  $downline->right_member_id.',';  
      $count = $count +1;
    }

    if($uids == 0){
      // echo $count;
      return;
    }else
    {
      $uids = substr($uids, 0, -1);
      echo $uids;
      $this->downline_count($uids, $count);
    }

  }

}
```

Comment: your question is not clear . Also, can you please post some of your codes that you have tried till now ?

Comment: Thanks for your reply Drudge

Comment: Here is  my function with which I try to get the total count of left and right members